# Prove that work done to establish current I in a coil of self inductance L is 1/2LI²

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

Also prove the first relation used in the proof:
dW/dT=EI
Where E is the EMF induced.

Comment: Energy(work) is force X displacement. Here force is e (EMF ita a force ) but how Idt ( current X time) become distance. Its charge.Can you explain it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMF $\mathcal{E}$ is defined as the work done in taking unit positive charge around a complete circuit.

So to take a charge of $dq$ around a complete circuit is $\mathcal{E} dq$.

$dq = Idt$

So the work done is $\mathcal{E}I dt$